# Reading data from NXP Mifare Ultralight NFC Tag with NFCTagReaderSession

Tags: ios, core-nfc

I'm trying to read the data from a NXP Mifare UltraLight tag but I always end up getting the error from CoreNFC: `Feature Not Supported`. Am I missing something or am I doing it wrong? Thanks in advance!

```
func tagReaderSession(_ session: NFCTagReaderSession, didDetect tags: [NFCTag]) {
                
        if case let NFCTag.miFare(tag) = tags.first! {
            
            session.connect(to: tags.first!) { (error: Error?) in

                let myAPDU = NFCISO7816APDU(instructionClass:0,
                                            instructionCode:0xB0,
                                            p1Parameter:0,
                                            p2Parameter:0,
                                            data: Data(),
                                            expectedResponseLength:16)
                    
                
                
                tag.sendMiFareISO7816Command(myAPDU) { response, sw1, sw2, error in
                    
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.textView.text = """
                            Identifier: \(tag.identifier.hexDescription)
                            Family: \(tag.mifareFamily.description)
                            Historical bytes: \(tag.historicalBytes?.hexDescription ?? "")
                            SW1: \(sw1), SW2: \(sw2)
                            Error: \(error?.localizedDescription ?? "No Error")
                            Response: \(response.hexDescription)
                            """
                    }
                    
                    guard error != nil && !(sw1 == 0x90 && sw2 == 0) else {
                        session.invalidate(errorMessage: "Application failure")
                        return
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you found a solution?